# How to disable “Limit IP address tracking” for all networks?

Tags: macos, ventura

I know one can disable “Limit IP address tracking” per Wi-Fi network.

Can  this be done once for all networks (both Ethernet and Wi-Fi)?

Answer (score 1):

As of iOS 16.6, the OS does not provide an option to disable "Limit IP address tracking" for all future networks.

That being said I had the same question due to concerns about Apple routing my web traffic. To hide IPs, there has to be proxying at some level. Even with https traffic, a proxy (Apple in this case) can still see the websites you visit due to [DNS leaks](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/7706/83281). I discovered this writing a simple [https proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165570/https-proxy-server-in-node-js/32104777#32104777).

To resolve this, I installed an Encrypted DNS iOS profile. The open source community maintains some here [encrypted dns profiles](https://github.com/paulmillr/encrypted-dns). A commonly used high-speed one is [google's https encrypted dns](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paulmillr/encrypted-dns/master/profiles/google-https.mobileconfig). I also like [cloudflare's family dns](https://github.com/paulmillr/encrypted-dns/raw/master/profiles/cloudflare-family-https.mobileconfig) for the kiddos. To set it up:

- Decided which encrypted DNS to use from the list
- Click the https download link on an iPhone
- Hit ok when asked to add the profile
- Open iPhone settings > above airplane mode it should say "Profile Downloaded". Tap on it.
- Hit install in the upper right corner.
- Now DNS leaks are prevented globally on the phone.

The source for it is somewhat readable, where you can see Google's IPv4 and IPv6 server addresses.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>DNSSettings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>DNSProtocol</key>
                <string>HTTPS</string>
                <key>ServerAddresses</key>
                <array>
                    <string>2001:4860:4860::8888</string>
                    <string>2001:4860:4860::8844</string>
                    <string>8.8.8.8</string>
                    <string>8.8.4.4</string>
                </array>
                <key>ServerURL</key>
                <string>https://dns.google/dns-query</string>
            </dict>
            <key>PayloadDescription</key>
            <string>Configures device to use Google Encrypted DNS over HTTPS</string>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Google DNS over HTTPS</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.dnsSettings.managed.f0ffd552-7183-4f2e-86e5-ee1ecad2a53a</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.dnsSettings.managed</string>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>556aa9a6-04bb-4144-9a1b-e1b20cda3b46</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>ProhibitDisablement</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string>Adds the Google DNS to Big Sur and iOS 14 based systems</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>Google Encrypted DNS over HTTPS</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.paulmillr.apple-dns</string>
    <key>PayloadRemovalDisallowed</key>
    <false/>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>B27E8E10-697D-4938-8745-7FFEEEED57A0</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Good answer. But if you want to use Cloudflare, maybe just downloading the 1.1.1.1 WARP app from the app store is simpler?

Comment: Does WARP let you set other DNS providers besides cloudflare?

Comment: No. You’ll be using Cloudflare with DoH